# I can't do appcfg.py update with google app engine, I receive error 500

Tags: python, google-app-engine

We have problem with deployment using `appcfg.py` update command.
In verbose mode we spotted this:

> 2018-03-21 11:00:01,257 INFO appengine_rpc_httplib2.py:303 Too many
>   retries for url
>   https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/deploy?app_id=

and at the end is:

> 2018-03-21 11:00:02,392 INFO appcfg.py:1688 Send:
>   /api/logclientdeploy, params= Error 500: --- begin server output ---
>
> #### Server Error
>
> A server error has occurred.
>
> --- end server output ---

Problem is occured only on one account what is used for deployment.

Please help resolve this issue .

Comment: Have the same issue with Java, I've already opened a ticket with Google and there is also an issue on the tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74877619

Answer (score 1):

Check that `app.yaml`, `cron.yaml` and other app configs are valid and correctly formatted. Strip them to the bare minimum needed to test your application. `500 A server error has occurred` on deployment is usually related to malformed configs.

Also note that `appcfg.py` is being deprecated 'soon' and you should switch to `gcloud app deploy`.

Comment: It could be right, but why it is working with another deployment account ? (only one specific account is not working)

Comment: Now it is working fine. Probably sombady from google fix it.